# How to save JSON list to SQLite and display to listview

Tags: android, json, database, sqlite, retrofit

I have already succeeded in parsing JSON, now I want to save the result of JSON to SQLite. My problem is I don't know how to save JSON list to SQLite. Please help me if you know how to save JSON to SQLite. Thanks in advance..

Btw, this is the json

```
[
  {
    "UserId": "3c652fc4-5dc4-4fa5-8c07-d27b0b657823",
    "Nationality": "ID",
    "Image": null,
    "IsAlreadyOnTextoaser": true,
    "IsAlreadyOnRequest": false,
    "LastActive": null,
    "LastActiveResume": "0 Days Ago",
    "FirstName": "dwi",
    "LastName": "wahyudi"
  },
  {
    "UserId": "cbb1f8bd-8016-4bc6-abd1-701fb353293d",
    "Nationality": "ID",
    "Image": null,
    "IsAlreadyOnTextoaser": true,
    "IsAlreadyOnRequest": false,
    "LastActive": null,
    "LastActiveResume": "0 Days Ago",
    "FirstName": "Wildan",
    "LastName": "Rachman"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guide you step by step!

you get a JsonArray as a response and you want to store in SQLite locally. This [Link](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) has answers all the code related stuff I will only walk you through the process.

You need to create database and table with appropriate number of columns and data type.

In SQLliteHelper create two public method one to add data and second to retrieve to display in the list.

Create instance of SQLliteHelper where you have access to the list and call method to add to the database and in your view where you want to display it call second method to retrieve the data from sqlite.

if you do not know how to use either listview or recyclerview please comment

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to save the JSON as a whole. Serialize it with for example [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), and save as Blob.

Comment: are you have a sample or tutorial about how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starter then use [ACtiveAndroid](http://www.activeandroid.com/)

If you want to use no sql database then you can use [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

I have wrritten a tutorial on Realm you can have a look at it from [here](http://blog.tamanneupane.com/simple-realm-demo-with-retrofit-and-weather-api/)

For loading it in list view is the similar process while you didnot use any database. The difference is just that now you have to first save data to database and load from database and add to list.